# show if n=4k+3 is a prime and a2+b2≡0(modn) , then

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This question has already been posted here.

[show if $n=4k+3$ is a prime and ${a^2+b^2} \equiv 0 \pmod n$ , then $a \equiv b \equiv 0 \pmod n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105034/show-if-n-4k3-is-a-prime-and-a2b2-equiv-0-pmod-n-then-a-equiv-b)

And it also has satisfactory answers however I have not yet studied quadratic residues and though the other answers are well written and I have understood them , my book has given a hint which goes this way :

"If a is not congruent to 0 modulo p then there exists an integer 'c' such that $$ ac\equiv 1\pmod n $$

Any help in approaching this problem using the above hint is appreciated

PS: Please do not mark this as duplicate as I want to understand the usage of this hint in solving the above problem

Comment: Do you know how to prove the statement of the hint itself? Because even though they supply it as a hint, a full solution needs to prove this as well.

Comment: Your hint mixes $p$ and $n$. Choose one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already got one good answer. The following alternative proof is more elementary.

Assume the claim does not hold. Let $n,a,b$ be a counterexample such that $n$ is as small as possible. By the hint,
$$(bc)^2+1\equiv(bc)^2+(ac)^2\equiv(a^2+b^2)c^2\equiv 0\pmod{n}.
$$
Let $d$ be an even number such that $0<d<n$ and $d\equiv\pm bc\pmod{n}$. Then $d^2+1=mn$ for some positive integer $m<n$. Now $m\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, and therefore $m$ has a prime factor $p$ such that $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$. Then $d^2+1^2\equiv 0\pmod p$, contradicting the minimality of $n$.

Comment: At the end of your first step where you have written (bc)^2 + 1 is congruent to 0 mod n can we use the statement that it is solvable only if n is of the form 4k + 1 and conclude the statement?

Comment: Yes, if you have proved that previously. I included a sketch of the easiest proof I know.

Answer (score 1):

Your hint was:

> If $a$ is not congruent to $0 \bmod n$ then there exists an integer $c$ such that $ac≡1\bmod n$

-- that is, if $a \not \equiv 0 \bmod n$ then $a$ has a modular inverse.

This would mean that we could take this $c$ and multiply through as follows:

$ a^2+b^2 \equiv 0 \\
1+(bc)^2\equiv 0 \\
(bc)^2\equiv -1$

meaning that $-1$ would be a [quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue)$\bmod n$.

We can show this is not the case directly: Since $n$ is prime, there is at least one [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) such that the [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of that number is $\phi(n)=n-1$. And taking one such primitive root $g$, we know that only even powers of $g$ are quadratic residues, but because $-1^2\equiv 1 \bmod n$ we have $g^{(n-1)/2}\equiv -1$ and $(n-1)/2 = 2k+1$ is an odd number, thus $-1$ is not a quadratic residue $\bmod n$.

So $a$ cannot have an inverse and we conclude $a\equiv 0 \bmod p$, with the same for $b$ by symmetry.